# making UIImage from bytes

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I have some data that is coming in xml tag from server and is in byte form
i have to convert it to UIImage 
I have tried various links on google and also here but no help...

I have used

```
`NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:@"/qf20+EWOfpJfjrUaU6n1fSRjXF8ALQZEDy8v7az8Ks8/................SVrttqCVOp9X0kDtYXh2EZIHYGYfVUlptlcpTLtfnn7PR6Tbpl8rpjy93lxcYmDftq9ZSCVDQnruZm6unQYfhis/Ife/bWfu0CHxnMc3Qam9VpEPk/vftp91gZ`+N5ilMOg2lbByAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAIAgCAID//2Q=="];
```

They told about the `dataWithBase64EncodedString:` method which is not there in my version of xcode.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

or

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

The data in the data parameter must be formatted to match the file format of one of the system’s supported image types.

Comment: Hi i also tried this but was unable to make a NSData from bytes , can you help?

Comment: go through the reference of NSData and see how to generate NSData from bytes. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: That page only give that method about which i already know and nothing more

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (where data is of the NSData type):

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data];